# Using __str__ & __repr__ Python methods to print a list from within a class method

Tags: python, string, printing, repr

Firstly, thank you for taking the time to consider my question - I've included a lot of code, I certainly appreciate your support!

I have written two classes:

PlayingCard and Deck

I would like to print the attribute [cards] form the method [shuffle_deck] from the class [Deck]. I have used the **str** magic method in the class which allows me to correctly output:

deck2 = Deck('♠') >
deck2.shuffle_deck() >
print(deck2)

but it does not work when I try to print a list directly from the method:

print(deck2.cards)

I've watched several youtube videos but am still struggling to understand why this is happening. I've read many posts on this forum, but I can't find a solution that particularly focuses on the contrast between printing the class object versus a list within a class method.

Once again, thank you for your help!

````
class PlayingCard():
    def __init__(self,value,suit):

        if value in ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A'] or value in [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'J','Q','K','A']:
            self.rank = str(value)
            
        else:
            print("Invalid rank!")
            raise Exception("Invalid rank!")
        
        if suit in '♥♦♣♠':
            self.suit = suit
        else:
            print('Invalid suit!') 
            raise Exception('Invalid suit!')

    def get_rank(self):
        return self.rank

    def get_suit(self):
        return self.suit
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.rank+" of " +self.suit


class Deck():
    ranks=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'J','Q','K','A']
    deck_cards=[]
    def __init__(self,suit = ['♥','♦','♣','♠']):
        self.suits = suit
        for rank in Deck.ranks:
            for suit in self.suits:
                card = PlayingCard(rank,suit)
                Deck.deck_cards.append(card)
        self.cards=[]
        for card in Deck.deck_cards:
            if card.get_suit() == suit:
                self.cards.append(card)

    def shuffle_deck(self):
        random.shuffle(Deck.deck_cards)

    def deal_card(self,count):
        deal_cards = []
        if count <= len(self.cards):
            deal_cards = random.sample(self.cards,count)
            for card in deal_cards:
                self.cards.remove(card)
            deal_card_str=''
            for card in deal_cards:
                deal_card_str += card.__str__()+", "
            print(deal_card_str[:-2])
        else:
            print('Cannot deal '+str(count)+' cards. The deck only has '+str(len(self.cards))+' cards left!')

    def __str__(self):
        full_deck=''
        for card in Deck.deck_cards:
            full_deck += card.__str__()+", "
        return full_deck[:-2]
    
    
deck2 = Deck('♠')
deck2.shuffle_deck()
print("I want to change this output to match the lower output", deck2.cards)
print("This is the correct format", deck2)```
````

Comment: You need to implement `__repr__` even if you just do `__str__ = __repr__`

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because deck2.cards is a list, so you'll need to iterate through that, like this:

```
deck2 = Deck('♠')
deck2.shuffle_deck()
print("I want to change this output to match the lower output"
print("{:s}".format(', '.join(deck2.cards)))
print("This is the correct format", deck2)
```

(Similarly to what you've done in the Deck class). This makes sense because each PlayingCard is a class instance of a single card, so there is no way for it to store the information on multiple cards, except in the way that you've already done it. In other words, the **str** function of PlayingCard only has access to its own data.